# math symbols to html in php?

Tags: php, mysql, math, format

I am doing website that test users math knowledge. I have access db with questions for test. BUt problem is format of tests are strange. here are some samples

```
1) Esaplan` $\dfrac{{110^6}\cdot{77^5}}{{55^8}\cdot{154^3}}$ . 

2) $\log _4\left( {x+12} \right)\cdot \log _x2=1$
```

Anybody help to write to mysql ?

Comment: http://www.mathjax.org/ might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like TeX markup, you will need something like http://phplatex.scarfboy.com/ to transform them.

Comment: i really would like to know why someone downvoted without stating whats wrong with the answer... this dont motivate to give answers..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [MathJAX](http://www.mathjax.org/) Javascript.  If you know LaTeX, you'll understand why.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer it is really great solution. but $ sign is still there. what does $ sign mean ? :)

Comment: Where are you seeing a dollar sign?  Download it here: http://www.mathjax.org/download/